# Can anyone else see the "edit tags" link?

Tags: discussion, tagging

When I hover my mouse near the tag list at the bottom of a question, I get a link "edit tags" that allows me to *just* edit the tags.

First question:

> Who else can see this?  Is it a moderator thing, or a reputation thing?

When I edit said tags, it still bumps the question (which, I believe, is status-by-design) *and* (more importantly) there is no indication that *all* I did was edit tags.  This, to me, seems a reasonable thing to have since then all those retaggings wouldn't be quite so irritating as it would be really obvious that all that was edited was the tags.

> Does this sound reasonable?

If so, it's worth transferring to meta.SO, but I thought I'd find out what the feeling was here first.

(Closest I could find on meta.SO was: [Edited by versus Retagged by](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29514/edited-by-versus-retagged-by) but that's over a year old)

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the first question: *I* don't see this.

2nd question: Yes, this sounds very reasonable, in particular if one sees that on the parent site a lot of retagging has been going on recently. I was slightly annoyed having to look at all those "bumped up questions" just to see if anything *real* happened. More importantly, it also makes the new questions and answers move away too fast, in my opinion. So I'm very much in favour of making this a feature request.

EDIT:

Sorry for this abuse, but there is only one reason for this edit: To say that I find this business very urgent now. No offence meant, Stefan, but at the moment I'm more than slightly annoyed by this feature that retags bump questions up. At this moment, 11 out of the 15 most recent questions are "modified [n] minutes ago" by Stefan, and I didn't even check if *all* of them are retags. Even though I don't use the tags often, I can see that they are useful, so on the one hand this retagging improves the site. On the other hand it's making it worse since it makes it a lot more difficult to find the new stuff.

Comment: I've got the same opinion - retagging should not bump up a question. I remember there have already been discussions regarding that with pros and cons, but I don't have a link.

Comment: Found it: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425/changing-tags-causes-questions-to-be-active

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks for your comments. Just wanted to post the link, too. Jeff answered with "status-bydesign", so what shall we do?

Comment: I guess we have to take it for granted... sorry for the "noise", as I was browsing through older questions in order to distract myself from newer. So I think: if we retag, let's do it at considerable long intervals.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's a 10k tools thing: see [the announcement](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/new-10k-feature-inline-tagging/).